# AWS NLB preserve client IP and proxy protocol v2 via CDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk, nlb

I am using a [NetworkLoadBalancedFargateService](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v1/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-ecs-patterns.NetworkLoadBalancedFargateService.html). The `NetworkLoadBalancer` created as part of the service does not have `preserve_client_ip.enabled` and `proxy_protocol_v2.enabled` set to `true`.

Below is what I have tried:

```
this.service = new NetworkLoadBalancedFargateService(this, serviceName, {
    // props
}

this.service.loadBalancer.setAttribute("preserve_client_ip.enabled", "true");
this.service.loadBalancer.setAttribute("proxy_protocol_v2.enabled", "true");
```

When I try to deploy the above, it gives me the error:

> Load balancer attribute key 'preserve_client_ip.enabled' is not recognized (Service: AmazonElasticLoadBalancing; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ValidationError; Request ID: 5a2b7202-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-50d464b8ade2; Proxy: null)

I know it can be done via console but was looking a way to do it in CDK. ([AWS Doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/network/load-balancer-target-groups.html))

Comment: `preserve_client_ip.enabled` is an attribute of a target group, not the load balancer itself.

Comment: @jordanm thanks for that. That was it. Instead of `this.service.loadBalancer`, I had to do `this.service.targetGroup` and everything worked.